# Not able to add data using ember-data Model

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

Controller/new-customer

```
  actions: {
    addInfo: function() {
      var name = this.get('name');
      var e_mail = this.get('e-address');
      var emoney = this.get('e-money');
      var newCustomer = this.store.createRecord('customers', {
        name    : name,
        email   : e_mail,
        emoney  : emoney
      });
      newCustomer.save();
      alert("You\'re added");
    }
```

Model/customers.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:DS.attr('string'),
    email:DS.attr('string'),
    emoney:DS.attr('number'),
    rev: attr('string')
});
```

templates/new-customer.hbs

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group control-group error">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Name</label>
        {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=name placeholder = "Enter your name" size="15"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        {{textarea type="text" class="form-control" value=e-address placeholder = "Enter your Email Address"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>E-Money</label>
        {{input type="number" class="form-control" value=e-money}}
    </div>
    <button {{action 'addInfo'}}type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit !!</button>
</form>
```

Am I missing something? Error I get on the console while clicking the submit button is:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.js:27458 Ember Data Request POST /customers returned a 404
Payload (text/html; charset=utf-8)
Cannot POST /customers

Error
    at AdapterError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:83957:16)
    at Class.handleResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85238:14)
    at ajaxError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85736:25)
    at Class.hash.error (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85310:23)
    at fire (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3637:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3767:7)
    at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9576:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9816:9)
defaultDispatch @ vendor.js:27458

Comment: Mostly model file name would be singular so change it to `customer` instead of `customers`. In createRecord mention model name as `customer` and ensure POST request to `/customers` exists.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Ember Data is working correctly but your  API server is not running or configured correctly.

`newCustomer.save();` attempts to save the record to your API and the error is explaining the exact issue:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
(Not  Found) vendor.js:27458 Ember Data Request POST /customers
returned a 404 Payload (text/html; charset=utf-8) Cannot POST /customers
```

Attempting to `POST` data to `/customers` on your API is resulting in a 404 at the server.